# React Native iOS Api call not working

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

Local iOS Building is working fine, but when I submit in iOS App Store they rejected App because HTTPs API call not working.

Comment: Are you using fetch or Axios for the API call ? If possible share the architecture to check

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @YogarajSaravanan i'm using fetch

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines in your plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
 <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
 <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: For the benefit of readers, would you explain in your answer what this does?

Comment: It forces an app to connect to web service over secure HTTPS connection.

Comment: @BhaveshRadadiya Not working for me. It is throwing me same exception.